# Requests Dialog only works with Canvas-View?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbdialogs

I've some page-tabs for a few fanpages and there I'd like to integrate the RequestDialog. But unfortunately it always tries to redirect the friend, that got a request, to the canvas page.

Is there a way to send the user to the page-tab, where his friend initially started the request dialog?

Thanks in advance,
Jurik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepting a request will always go to the canvas page with the `request_ids` parameter added.  See the "User Response" section of this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Obviously you could write code to detect when the user arrives with the `request_ids` parameter and redirect to another page, like your Page tab, for example by setting `window.top.location.href` in JavaScript inside your canvas iframe.

Comment: Hehehe... seems like window.top.location.href is one of the most used workarounds on facebook ;) - thanks for your answer.