# FB app requests redirecting to canvas page instead of tab page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-canvas

When users send app requests, the requests point to the canvas page instead of the page tab.

I know the solution is to point your Canvas App URL to a page that redirects to the page tab. However, it's not working.

This is the JS on my redirect page:

```
top.location.replace("#{PAGE_TAB_URL}");
```

Going to the redirect page directly (myapp.com/redirect) will redirect to the page tab fine. But for some reason, requests don't work. When users click to view the request, my app returns a 404.

Is there some problem with `top.location.replace` within Facebook?

The following question's solution did not work for me: [FB app request points to canvas page instead of page tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949259/fb-app-request-points-to-canvas-page-instead-of-page-tab)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my routes file (it's a Rails app), I was only `get`ing /redirect, and wasn't handling `post`, which is what happens in a page tab. Working solution:

On redirect page:

```
`window.top.location.href = "#{PAGE_TAB_URL}";`
```

routes.rb:

```
`match "redirect" => "home#redirect"`
```